# Which option/tool shows tenuring thresholds for Java?

Tags: java, jvm

I once found a way to show the current tenuring threshold (among other things) for the Hotspot JVM. I believe it was a JVM option that was configurable to print the information at a specified interval to stdout. I can't find it now. What option/tool am I looking for to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for : `-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution`.  Did you look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)?  I should ask: *Why do you care?*  It's generally not recommended to tinker with these flags unless you really know what you're doing.  I would stick to sizing my heap and let the JVM ergonomics do the rest.

Comment: Doh. Yes, I've been poring over that page, and I even tried that option, or thought I did... I just copied it from the page verbatim and forgot that I had to change the '-' to '+'. Thanks for the tip. As for why, it's more of a curiosity than anything. I'm going to give a talk on debugging tools, and one of my sample apps that shows what happens when you're pushing the limits of your heap space made me think of the threshold because of the way the GC was acting. Don't worry. I'm not doing anything crazy with it :)